# How Does This Equation even work dimensional analysis: $λ=\frac{hc}{E}$

Tags: linear-algebra, physical-chemistry

equation:

${λ=\frac{hc}{E}}$

---

units:

λ = m

E = ${J}$

h = ${\frac{J}{s}}$

c = ${\frac{m}{s}}$

---

trying to isolate to get ${λ = m}$:

${λ = \frac{hc}{E}}\Rightarrow{λ = \frac{Jm}{Js^2}}\Rightarrowλ =\frac{m}{s^2}$

---

And here I get stuck, I've been trying this for hours, please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unit of $h$, Planck’s constant, is actually $$J \ s $$

So $$\lambda=\frac{hc}{e} = \frac{[J][s] \cdot [m] [s]^{-1} }{[J]} = [m]$$

Comment: are you telling me its not `j/s` its `j*s`?

Comment: @Nickotine That’s exactly what I’m telling you.

Comment: ${λ = \frac{hc}{e}}\Rightarrow{λ = \frac{jsm}{js}}\Rightarrow {λ = m}$   |                                      
                                                                                                                             you've got to be kidding me I wasted so much time on this, so in maths you can signify multiplication with a `.`? `h= 6.62607015×10−34 J⋅s` I mistook that for divide...

Comment: thank you @Tavish....

Comment: @Nickotine Yes, turns out there are multiple ways to show multiplication ( $\times, *, \cdot$). You’re welcome.